# Multiple issues - notification bar, loss of data on calendar

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

Suddenly my notification bar wont slide down. I get the beeps for the notifications but am unable to see any notifications.

the settings button on the right hand top also has vanished. I have to scroll down to the settings icon to go to settings.

The calendar has suddenly become blank. Lost all data.

The sync function with google is not working.

Could anybody please help?

Comment: What phone? Any recollection of what you did before this started happening?

Comment: Moto g 2nd gen. The calendar was not syncing with Google calendar on PC. I called Motorola Customer Service who asked me to go to Accounts and remove the calendar and contacts. I asked her if I would lose the data and she said no. When we will add them back, all data will be available. After I removed Calendar and Contacts she was unable to get them back. I called their Level 2 who could retrieve the contact list but not the calendar